# Using the credentials element in the web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am following along in "Pro ASP.NET Mvc 3 Framework Framework" book. In the book they are showing that in the web.config file you can use the credentials element, and the user element to hard-code a username and password for your admin settings. When I do this I get the error, "Unrecognized element 'credentials'". Yet if I press F12 to go to definition, I can find the element in the xml. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem until I found the following example on MSDN's website which helped me resolve my issue.

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
   <forms 
      name=".ASPXAUTH" 
      loginUrl="login.aspx" 
      protection="All"  
      timeout="30" 
      path="/" 
      requireSSL="false" 
      slidingExpiration="true">
      <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1"></credentials>
   </forms>
   <passport redirectUrl="internal" />
</authentication>
```

In short, you have to nest credentials inside the forms tag.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN Dcoumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e01fc50a.aspx):

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms name="401kApp" loginUrl="/login.aspx">
            <credentials passwordFormat = "SHA1">
               <user 
                  name="UserName1" 
                  password="SHA1EncryptedPassword1"/>
               <user 
                  name="UserName2" 
                  password="SHA1EncryptedPassword2"/>
               <user 
                  name="UserName3" 
                  password="SHA1EncryptedPassword3"/>
            </credentials>
         </forms>
      </authentication>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It seems you may want to use `passwordFormat = "Clear"` if you're storing a plain password, but obviously this should only be done during development / prototyping with a TEST account, because having your password in the clear is a BIG NO NO!

Comment: I've done that. Still get the same error. Here is the config markup <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
   <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
    <user name="admin" password="secret"/>
   </credentials>
  </authentication>

Comment: @James Just to make sure, you do have it nested in the normal configuration/system.web sections right?  If so, what error are you seeing?